# Xcode 9.3 breaking my AdHoc provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

This has happened on 2 machines for me. My AdHoc(use for Hockey App) provisioning profiles were working fine until the last update. Now I get the:

Provisioning profile "HAAdHoc19" doesn't include signing certificate "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

error when I select those profiles. I've removed the certs from my keychain, generated a new one, generated a new AdHoc profile(or 2) and still get the error. Any ideas?